# Problems with CORS in NestJS

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, nestjs

I have a problem with CORS when deploy my API to Google App Engine.

In main.ts file, I tried adding 3 different settings:

1:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
```

2:

```
app.enableCors();
```

3:

```
const whiteList = ['http://localhost:4200',];
app.enableCors({     
    origin: whiteList,
 });
```

I tried each one separately on each deployment.

I'm requesting the API from Angular in my local, not sure what else I'm missing.

**The errors I get:**

Request URL:

```
https://gle*********appspot.com/auth/login
```

Referrer Policy:

```
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://gleaming-****.uc.r.appspot.com/auth/login' from origin
> 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

[image]